# Octave - comparing unequal matrices and finding equal elements

Tags: matrix, compare, octave

I have two matrices of different dimensions and I want to compare if any of the elements in their first columns match (and eventually remove rows where there is a match). Looping just takes too much time so I am trying vectorized version but nothing I've tried worked. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Example.

```matlab
A    = magic(3);
B    = magic(6);

UpTo       = min( size( A, 1 ), size( B, 1 ) );
CommonRows = B(1 : UpTo, 1) == A(1 : UpTo, 1);

B( CommonRows, : ) = []   % B with rows of same element in column 1 removed
```

Comment: Almost but not quite... Works only for same dimensions and for sorted indices in increasing order. Returns B with just one row removed if match was found in the first 3 rows as is dimension of A.

Comment: @Tijana Yes! This is what you asked. :)  Of course what you asked could be interpreted in many ways, I just picked the one I thought you probably meant. Would you like to make your question more specific? Perhaps add an example of inputs and what you expect to happen (and what you expect NOT to happen)?

Comment: E.g. are the elements in the first column expected to be unique? Or do you rely on their position being the same?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enough. I want to compare values of elements in the first column of two matrices of unequal size to check if there is overlap with some elements, and if an element is present in 1st column of both matrices then I remove a row with that element from first matrix. Btw elements in 1st colum are sorted in ascending order. I could separate out that column and use intersect with index command and loop over those indices but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Something like setdiff(A(:,1),B(:,1))  but that returns whole rows and not just unique elements.

Comment: Hi @Tijana thanks for clarifying. Don't just clarify to me though! Please feel free to edit your question and include this information. Preferably, also include your "loop" version so that it 's clear exactly what you're after. This way you increase your chances of 'someone' answering, not just me, and also it's more helpful to future users who come here with a similar problem. (I will try to update my answer later if I have time)

Comment: but as a quick thought, you can probably use setdiff like you say here, and then use a "member of" function to create a logical index for indexing rows in your first matrix.

Comment: Still struggling... Apparently the last way I proposed only takes one (last) unique appearance of a value and so it fails in my case where I have repeating values in both matrices I am comparing. If I have a value 1 three times in matix A and 1 is also appearing in matrix B say two times, I want to take out all rows from A where 1 appears and include those rows in B.  Side note: I tried to include my loop but not sure how to make it appear here with gray background like a code and not like text, so I gave up for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the last thing I tried and almost got it but doesn't work when I have repeating values in both matrices.

```
 [C,iC]=setdiff(A(:,1),B(:,1))
 [D,iD]=intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1))

 newA=A(iC,:)
 newBtemp=[A(iD,:);B]
 newB=sort(newBtemp)
```

But I think I got it now finally:

```
common=ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1))
temp=A(common,:)
A(common,:)=[]
newB=sort([temp;B])
```